# vba specialcells visible define range

Tags: vba, excel, range, visible

I am trying to use the SUM function to add all of the visible cells in column I from sRow to dRow (variables are starting and ending rows for a date range) but keep getting error 91 "object variable or with block variable not set" with this line of code:

```
vRange = Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

I am not entirely sure why this throws an error because this works

```
visibleSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & dRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

I am trying to get this block of code to return the sum of range "I, start date" to "I, end date" only counting positive numbers.

```
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query_from_TCM95").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="10"

        vRange = Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & dRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        visibleSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(vRange, ">0")
        MsgBox (visibleSum)
```

EDIT - Thanks for the comments! both helped :D

Ultimately this counts hours each department worked where each department has its own number. 10, 20, etc. When I define my range for department 95, for the first week there are no cells which throws error 1004. That happens when the visible cells do not contain data for the date range specified. I attempted a couple different if statements this being one:

```
If Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & dRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Is Nothing Then
        Else

            Set vRange = Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & dRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            visibleSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, vRange)
            MsgBox (visibleSum)
        End If
```

Specifically this line

```
Set vRange = Range("I" & sRow & ":" & "I" & dRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

gives error 1004 no cells found

I have 8 different Criteria that I have to iterate through. I am thinking about a select case but not sure if that will be efficient or actually accomplish what I need.

Any thoughts or tips are greatly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: use `Set` keyword to set objects (like ranges are) variables: `Set vRange = Range("I" ...`

Comment: Use `Subtotal` instead of `Sum` - that's what it does. ;)

Comment: Thank you! you helped a lot! when i try to define the range sometimes it is nothing if there isnt hours for that department that week. would you all be able to help me with my edited question??